# Best way to print a right-aligned form-layout with QPainter

Tags: qt, qpainter

I want to paint/print the 2 columns (labels and values) side by side but with content aligned to the right. Like this (but not using a monospace font) :

```
  label:      1
    lbl:  568.0
```

Is there a simpler way than computing width of each column with QFontMetrics ?

What I have in mind now is something like this :

```
 painter->drawText(QRectF(leftMargin,
                          topMargin,
                          maxLabelColumnWidth,
                          maxTextHeight),
                   Qt::AlignRight,
                   "label:");

 painter->drawText(QRectF(leftMargin + columnSpacing + maxLabelColumnWidth,
                          topMargin,
                          maxValueColumnWidth,
                          maxTextHeight),
                   Qt::AlignRight,
                   "1");

// etc, adding maxTextHeight to y for next line
```

Comment: You are already using `Qt::AlignRight`, does this not work?

Comment: Yes it does, I just wondered if there was a simpler way to do something like this, print layout with columns, align content of columns etc (without computing all string width mainly...)

Comment: Why use the `QPainter` for what looks like a `QGridLayout`?

Comment: @JeffreyvandeGlind : exactly a QFormLayout or QGridLayout yes, but I need to print it into a PDF (or paint it on custom widget above other things). Maybe QWidget::render could do that for me though... I've never tried it.